# Attempting to run multiple tests using Xcode's new UI testing fails

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode7, xcode7-beta3, xcode-ui-testing

When I try to run multiple UI tests at the same time in the new Xcode beta, it fails after the first test, with the error "UI Testing Failure: App state is still not terminated" for each test after the first. Anyone got a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include a

`func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
}`

function?

It's needed to terminate the app state after each test before it is re-initialized by the

`func setUp() {
    super.setUp();
    XCUIApplication().launch
}`

Comment: Can you please add some code code blocks? This is really hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. It seems that, at least in my case, application had never been terminated.

I solved it by putting the following statement in the `setUp()` method:

`continueAfterFailure = false`

This should stop a running test process after first failure.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post a comment, so I will try to answer your question while getting some clarification.

I have faced this issue when running on physical devices. On simulator I did not face this issue. So are you facing this issue when running on device or simulator or both?

If its a device, then there is a known bug which has been reported to Apple. To overcome this issue, at runtime I have inserted dummy test cases between two genuine test cases.